# Problem include eps figure in latex

Tags: texstudio, eps, includegraphics

I am using Texstudio to write my paper and I need to include graphics figures as eps format. I have a problem when I use \includegraphics, as shown in the below image the eps figure, is converted from eps to PDF then the PDF image is added into the resulted PDF. Is it available to import eps image without converting it into PDF?

Thanks in advance

[image]

output PDF file

[image]

the ABER_VS_SNR.eps was greater after I have run the code.

[image]

Comment: There are many similar questions already out there. Maybe try to read them first.

Comment: ...hmm, everything in a PDF file must be PDF... (ok, you can embed bitmaps, but...). I do not understand what is the problem; is it possible that this is a kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay. I want to clarify one point you mean that If output Generated output latex file is PDF then the eps image with being converted PDF also is that correct?

Comment: Did you have a look at the linked question and the answers?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Yes, I have read the link you provide in your answer as far I understand from the answer. If the output of my code is  PDF file then eps figure will be converted into PDF also and if I want to keep the figure as eps then the output file should be DVI file correct?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin thanks for the advice  modified the question as your request .

Comment: Short answer: I recommend to use a PDF workflow and forget DVI.

Comment: Spend time to figure out how to generate a PDF output from your application.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks you for your advice.

Comment: Don't use `epsfig`. `graphicx` is sufficient for this. Also, compile with LaTeX, not pdfLaTeX.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you want to use the EPS file. The converted PDF file looks the same, so what would be the advantage of using the EPS? If you change the EPS file _after_ you compile, then you should just compile again, then the conversion to PDF is also applied again. In general when you include an image, in any format (png, jpg, pdf, eps) and the image changes you need to recompile, the image is not 'linked' in any way, it is directly copied into to the final document (i.e., you can delete the image file afterwards and the image will still be in the pdf).

Comment: @EhabBuaod indeed you didn't, there is no MWE. that's why the question has been closed. Should you edit the question with a MWE it could be reopened.
https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228